# How to read and write from existing mongoDB by IP address?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

**How can I read and write from an existing mongoDB by IP address?**

I learn from here (*pymongo*): https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/connect-to-mongodb-from-python/

Saying that technically using (Windows + pymongo + python script) can read and write to mongoDB.
I have IP address and existing mongoDB(already have company's collection/table),

*environment: Windows 11 cmd , python*

I should make more clear that I have actual mongoDB collection/table with IP address 196.xxx.xxx.xxx (x is for actual ip address )

- **tried .py code for read and write from an existing mongoDB by IP address**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
import pandas as pd

client =pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://196.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017")
print(client)

with client:
    
    db = client.cloud_db
    print(db.collection_names())
```

**and output is not found:**

```
C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB>python 1.py
MongoClient(host=['196.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\1.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(db.collection_names())
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 3194, in __call__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'collection_names' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

> online image link:(about the actual mongoDB I want to connect, print,
> write) https://postimg.cc/64qcCpjq

if I want to **list up all the collections/tables from `cloud_db` (in the mongoDB picture** above) and maybe **read and write**  to  `cloud_db`'s one of the collection named `eform_detail` , then what should I do??

**here is my tried code after using `client.list_database_names()`**

```
import pymongo

#connect to my desire mongoDB by IP address
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://196.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017")

#name my DB name
mydb_Name="cloud_db"

# set mydb will have all properties from myclient[mydb_Name]
mydb = client[mydb_Name]

#print all DB name
print("now exsisting DB are:  ",client.list_database_names())

#if DB exsist, then print it out
# and the "cloud_db" already exsist 
dblist = client.list_database_names()
if mydb_Name in dblist:
  print("Your DB: {0}exsist!!!!".format(mydb_Name))
```

**and error raise:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("now exsisting DB are:  ",client.list_database_names())
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1839, in list_database_names
    return [doc["name"] for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True, comment=comment)]
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1812, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 843, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(_cmd, read_preference, session)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1413, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1229, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 272, in select_server
    server = self._select_server(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 261, in _select_server
    servers = self.select_servers(selector, server_selection_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 223, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(selector, server_timeout, address)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 238, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Could not reach any servers in [('mongodb', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames or IPs?, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6347a91a4c61799b7b1594ac, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>]>
```

my expect output is : (then I could do read and write later)
mongoDB pic : https://postimg.cc/64qcCpjq

> now exsisting DB are: [ 'admin' , 'cloud_db']
>
> inside cloud_db are: [ 'asset' , 'bas_bom_plain' , 'bas_part_info' ,
> 'bom' , 'comments' , 'def' , 'def_detail' , 'doc' , 'eform',
> 'eform_detail' ........etc(the collections in picture) ]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I guess I'm missing the point of your question.  Isn't accessing a Mongo db via an IP address exactly what your code is demonstrating how to do?

Comment: Are you maybe hung up on the "create" thing?  The code will only create a database if one doesn't already exist.  If there is already a database with the name "joy101344444444444added", your code isn't going to blow it away.  It's just going to use it.  Also, technically, your code won't create a new database even if it doesn't already exist.  Mongo doesn't actually create a database until the first time that you store something in it.

Comment: hi, @CryptoFool I'm aiming to read and write from existing mongoDB's collection/ table by IP address and pymongo theory. I add some more detail, wish that could help

Comment: Do you mean to use [`db.list_collection_names()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.list_collection_names)?

Comment: yeah @rickhg12hs, if I want to **list up all the collections/tables from `cloud_db` (in the mongoDB picture)** and maybe ** read and write**  to  `cloud_db`'s one of the collection named `eform_detail` , then what should I do

Comment: @che-yu After you are connected as a client in `pymongo`, you can do all the normal MongoDB operations.  Have a look at `pymongo`'s [tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) and [examples](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/index.html) to get started.

Comment: that cool @rickhg12hs , but seems I haven't success connect to my desire `mongodb://196.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017`  and  print expect output yet, I afread my .py script is wrong, that cannot conect well

Comment: I've never used `NoSQLBooster` and I'm wondering if it can show you the MongoDB connection string it is using to successfully connect to the server.  Until you are properly connected, nothing else will work.

Comment: that all I know,  therefore I make my firends asking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051850/pymongo-checking-mongodb-ip-address-is-working-while-mongodb-compass-didt-fin) try to figure out if IP address is valid

Comment: If you click on "Connect" in `NoSQLBooster`, is there a submenu that will show you the current connection string and any extra parameters?